# x86-64 Assembly test - jle

Tags: assembly, x86, branch

This:

```
testl   %esi, %esi
jle .L3
movl    %esi, %eax
```

If `testl` do a logical AND on `esi` the result can't never be *less* but only *equals*, either if `esi` is 0. In this way `movl` can't be reached. It's that true, or I'm missing somethings.

Step two:

```
f1:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    testl   %esi, %esi
    jle .L3
    movl    %esi, %eax
.L2:
    incb    (%rdi)
    incq    %rdi
    decq    %rax
    jne .L2
.L3:
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

In a hypothetical C translation if `.L3` consists of `pop` then `ret` and the branch take place it's possible to determine the value returned by the function?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"Less than or equal" is defined as: `ZF=1 or SF != OF`

The `TEST` instruction sets `ZF` and `SF` based on a logical `AND` between the operands, and clears `OF`.

So in effect you end up with the condition `ZF or SF`, meaning "Less than or equal to zero" (i.e. the jump would be taken if `(signed int)esi <= 0` in this case).

**Edit**: For the second part of your question, it looks like it's doing something along these lines:

```
void f1(char *c, int len)
{
    if (len > 0) {
        for (i = len; i != 0; i--) {
            (*c)++;
            c++;   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In a hypothetical C translation if `.L3` consists of `leave` and `ret` and the branch take place, this means that the function return `0`? Otherwise if `jle` fails and after the `movl` instruction there's an epilogue it woulds mean that the function return the integer value `eax`?

Comment: Integral values are returned in `eax` on IA-32, so in the scenario you describe it would return the value of `esi` if `esi > 0`, otherwise it would return whatever was already in `eax`.

Comment: If I don't have this information I can't determine what value is returned?

Comment: Not sure which information you're referring to. Given a complete disassembly of a function it should be possible to determine what (if anything) it will return for a given input, unless it calls other functions that you neither have the code for or a description of.

Comment: I don't think that code returns anything meaningful. See my updated answer.

Comment: It's confusing. `.L3.` returns without modify `_ax` and that make me think to a `void` procedure. But in `.L2` `_ax` is accessed.